# Input non-sequential data of arbitrary size to network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language

I have a case where I want to feed a network with polylines of data. The problem is that the input can be any number of polylines and the polylines can consist of any number of points. If we instead convert the polylines to vectors the requirements might be easier to formulate:

- Network with a variable number of input vectors.
- All vectors have a variable length (independent).
- The input is NOT sequential.
- For one set of input only one output is requested (i.e not very similar to NLP/translation)

Any suggestions? I know that I can provide the network with a zero-padded 2D vector with the maximum number of "polylines" and the maximum number of "points" in each polyline as size but I would prefer not to since they can vary a lot.

I have previously converted the polylines to images of fixed size with success but I am looking for an alternative way to do it without the loss of precision that comes from converting from polylines to an image.

Answer (score 2):

A feed-forward network has a fixed number of layers with a fixed number of neurons in them. This means the input of the network always **has to have the same feature dimensionality**. [1](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/26199/why-do-feedforward-neural-networks-require-the-inputs-to-be-of-a-fixed-size-whi),[2](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/using-variable-sized-input-is-padding-required/18131)

It is not possible to effectively train a feed-forward neural network that has inputs of different types/sizes. The standard solution to this problem would be either padding (which you said you do not want) or truncation (which loses information).

*An approach worth looking into would be [embedding](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/embeddings/video-lecture), which means translating any input into an arbitrary feature space of fixed size (e.g. representing each input as a 64-dimensional vector). But of course, the problem of variable input sizes remains the same and embedding would introduce an additional loss of information. So this might not be helpful for you at all.*

To my knowledge, it is not feasible to train a neural network on variable input sizes. However, the padding approach keeps all the information of the input samples for only slightly higher computational cost. I suggest you give this a try, even with highly varying input sizes.

[Also check out this question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/how-can-neural-networks-deal-with-varying-input-sizes)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Have you read anything similar to this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.04259.pdf where they instead treat the polyline input as a graph?

I do not fully understand the article but that is at least my understanding of what they are proposing.

Comment: Very interesting paper, thanks for the info! I've had a quick look at it, from what I understood the team minimized input size by exploiting similarities in vectors (e.g. the end of one vector is the start of another). This can be seen as some form of data embedding, which is exactly what I proposed. However, this approach only saves a portion of the computational cost, it does not relate to the problem of fixed input sizes. This is more of an "optimization" for a very specific domain of ML, not a general approach you can take.

Comment: But they still seem to be able to fit in an arbitrary amount of (in this case) map elements into a network by using a vector network instead of a traditional conv net. Right?

Comment: It is **impossible** to fit an arbitrary amount of data into a fixed size (a very logical statement, just think about writing a story with only limited amount of words). You can go deeper into information theory if you are interested in this phenomenon.

Comment: "However, by embedding the ordering information into vectors, constraining the connectivity of subgraphs based on the polyline groupings, and encoding
attributes as node features, our method is particularly suitable to encode structured map annotations and agent trajectories" Here you can see they are embedding the data, meaning information is lost in their transformation process of making the input fixed-size.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense